# regarding thrift function return list

Tags: java, thrift

i have thrift service with a function returning list of Object ABC:

```
struct ABC
{

     1: string user_id;

     2: string foo;

     3: optional list<string> data;
}


list<ABC> getABCByUser(1:required string user_id, 2:i32 limit,3:i32 pageId, 4:string lastDocID)
throws (1:InvalidRequestException ire, 2:UnavailableException ue, 3:TimedOutException    te)
```

server side written by c++
I print out result returned by server side, data in ABC instance is NOT null in the response of getABCByUser.

How ever on client side which is written by java:
I set break point in the code generated by thrift on java side, data in ABC instance is null, other fields are not null.
it looks like a issue on the client side. Any idea how to fix this issue?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the generated java-code?

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem with you. I found that if delete the "optional" modifier before list, the return value will be right. But I don't know why we can't use "optional" before list.

Answer (score 0):

If you think you may have found a bug, please open a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT) ticket and add your reproducible test case. This makes it easier for others to have a look at it. Thank you!