# Apache Thrift: When use "optional' before a list, C++ server seems not to return it correctly

Tags: c++, perl, thrift

**Hi!** every one, I have a problem similar with this one:

[regarding thrift function return list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052957/regarding-thrift-function-return-list)

When a list has a "optional" modifier, the thrift C++ server will always return it as null/undef.

Additionally, if a struct contained by a optional list, any of the struct's field, can't be set to "optional", or, a null/undef value will be returned.

After deleting all the "optional" modifier, everything is OK.

Could anybody tell me why I can't use "optional" before a list ?

---

Here is the thrift file:

```
namespace cpp thrifttest
namespace perl thrifttest

struct Pair {
    1: optional string a, 
    2: optional string b
}

struct Result {
    1: optional list<string> strList,
    2: optional list<Pair> pairList
}

service Test {

    Result listTest()

}
```

Here is the C++ code (server):

```
#include "gen-cpp/Test.h"
#include <thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>
#include <thrift/server/TSimpleServer.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TServerSocket.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TBufferTransports.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

using namespace ::apache::thrift;
using namespace ::apache::thrift::protocol;
using namespace ::apache::thrift::transport;
using namespace ::apache::thrift::server;

using boost::shared_ptr;

using namespace  ::thrifttest;

class TestHandler : virtual public TestIf {
    public:
        TestHandler() {
            // Your initialization goes here
        }

        void listTest(Result& _return) {

            _return.strList.push_back("Test");
            _return.strList.push_back("one level list");
            cout << "strList size: " << _return.strList.size() << endl;

            Pair pair;
            pair.a = "Test";
            pair.b = "two level list";
            _return.pairList.push_back(pair);
            cout << "pairList size: " << _return.pairList.size() << endl;

            printf("call listTest\n");
        }

};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int port = 9595;
    shared_ptr<TestHandler> handler(new TestHandler());
    shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new TestProcessor(handler));
    shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket(port));
    shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());
    shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

    TSimpleServer server(processor, serverTransport, transportFactory, protocolFactory);
    server.serve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the perl code (client):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.12;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use utf8;
use Data::Dumper;

use lib 'gen-perl';

use thrifttest::Test;
use thrifttest::Constants;
use thrifttest::Types;

use Thrift;
use Thrift::BinaryProtocol;
use Thrift::Socket;
use Thrift::BufferedTransport;


my $socket    = new Thrift::Socket('localhost', 9595);
my $transport = new Thrift::BufferedTransport($socket, 1024, 1024);
my $protocol  = new Thrift::BinaryProtocol($transport);
my $client    = new thrifttest::TestClient($protocol);


eval {
    $transport->open();
    my $result = $client->listTest;
    say Dumper($result);
    $transport->close();
};
say $@ if $@;
```

C++ server output:

```
strList size: 2
pairList size: 1
call listTest
```

perl client output:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'pairList' => undef,
                 'strList' => undef
               }, 'thrifttest::Result' );
```

PS: My development environment is CentOS 7, GCC 4.8.3, Perl 5.16, thrift 0.9.3

Comment: "*Could anybody tell me why I can't use "optional" before a list?*" - sounds strange, indeed. Could you narrow it down to a more handy (i.e. much smaller) test case and file a JIRA ticket?

Comment: Looks as if the `__isset.nBestAlignPairList` flag is not properly set in this case, but the structure member is present. Sounds like a bug to me. File a ticket. As a workaround, you could try to call `__set_nBestAlignPairList()` explicitly, which should set the flag.

Comment: @JensG Thank you for your response! I have already commit a bug report to JIRA , an change to simple case to reproduce the problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3473

Comment: Anything wrong with my answer below?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was wrong, it is not a real bug, it is just some unfortunate design that is not really fool proof and allows the user to make Dumb Things™. The problem lies in the semantics of the `optional` operator and how it is implemented for C++.

Lets asssume we have this piece of IDL:

```
struct Xtruct2
{
  1: i8     byte_thing,  
  2: Xtruct struct_thing,
  3: i32    i32_thing
}
```

The generated code, in particular the `write()` method, looks like this:

```
uint32_t Xtruct2::write(::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot) const {
  //...
  xfer += oprot->writeFieldBegin("struct_thing", ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_STRUCT, 2);
  xfer += this->struct_thing.write(oprot);
  xfer += oprot->writeFieldEnd();
  //...
}
```

If we now modify the IDL and add the `optional` specifier:

```
struct Xtruct2
{
  1: i8     byte_thing,  
  2: optional Xtruct struct_thing,
  3: i32    i32_thing
}
```

The generated code looks slightly different:

```
uint32_t Xtruct2::write(::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot) const {
  //...
  if (this->__isset.struct_thing) {
    xfer += oprot->writeFieldBegin("struct_thing", ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_STRUCT, 2);
    xfer += this->struct_thing.write(oprot);
    xfer += oprot->writeFieldEnd();
  }
  //...
}
```

Thrift has three kinds of requiredness: `required`, `optional` and default. The latter is assumed implicitly if neither `required` nor `optional` was specified (that's why there is no special keyword for default requiredness). The semantics vis-à-vis reading and writing those fields is as follows:

```
    requiredness        write field?        read field?         
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    required            always              always, must be present
    (default)           always              if present, may be missing
    optional            only if set         if present, may be missing
```

So what `optional` changes compared to the default is the behaviour of the write method. While a default field is always written, an `optional` field is only written **conditionally**. That is checked by means of the `__isset` flags, which consist of a bitset, one bit for each field that is not `required`. If the corresponding bit flag within `__isset` is set, the field value can be used. If the bit flag is not present, the field value has not been initialized and thus should not be used.

So far this would not be a much of a problem. But there's a trap that you managed to hit: Default and `optional` fields can be accessed and used in C++ **even if the bit flag is not set** because they are just there. In case of default requiredness, this is not a big deal: You assign your values, and since the field is always written, basically nothing bad happens. The bit flag for the field is set when the field is deserialized (see generated code).

However, things change when you opt-in to `optional`: Now all of a sudden **you** are responsible to set the flag properly, either by accessing `__isset` directly or by means of the generated setter method, in our case this one:

```
void Xtruct2::__set_struct_thing(const Xtruct& val) {
  this->struct_thing = val;
__isset.struct_thing = true;
}
```

My assumption was that it should not be possible to access an optional field that has not been set, but it turned out that this seems to be by design. I still think that the design is a bit too much error prone here.